# Error when installing libapache2-mod-fastcgi for apache2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2

When i'm trying to install libapache2-mod-fastcgi for apache as following:

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

```
root@server:~# sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libapache2-mod-fastcgi is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up libapache2-mod-fastcgi (2.4.7~0910052141-1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-fastcgi (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-fastcgi
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What's wrong ? I've done this before on Ubuntu, But this time an error came up.

Both `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get install -f`

```
Setting up libapache2-mod-fastcgi (2.4.7~0910052141-1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-fastcgi (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-fastcgi
```

Comment: I guess i solved this out by reinstalling dpkg `sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg`

Answer (score 3):

There was a better solution (yours doesn't works for me):

Uninstall the module

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove libapache2-mod-fastcgi
```

Purge config/data

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove libapache2-mod-fastcgi
```

Then you can install the module

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi
```